# How to disable show password?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, authentication

I work for a school and I want to disable this part. When ever the network goes down and it has to reauthenticate, the kids have a chance to see the password. How can I disable that part?

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i believe this has been asked before, and there's no way to solve it, unless network manager source code is modified.

Comment: You cannot keep that a secret even when you recompile the network manager source code, unless you're hard-coding it in the source and encrypt it there!

Answer (score 1):

I think, but I am not sure, that preventing ordinary users from any control whatsoever over the Network Manager functions also prevents them from seeing the password. This is a setting I use in my lab, and I think I checked it to see if passwords could be visible, but that was long ago and I don't remember for sure:

```
# cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/disable-network-control.pkla 
[Wifi management]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no

[Wifi sysad management]
Identity=unix-group:sudo;unix-user:root
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

The configuration is very readable - it denies access to all users for any action related to Network Manager, and then allows them for members of the `sudo` group and the `root` user.

So (assuming of course your students use unprivileged accounts), you could apply the same restriction to their accounts, while exempting your administrator accounts.

Answer (score -1):

I use this configuration , and only the root user can see the WiFi password.
The users can't  see the password.

This is the path, I changed the polkit setings

cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/disable-network-control.pkla

[ users are not able to edit or to see pasword]

Identity=unix-user:*

Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.*

ResultActive=no

Comment: Please explain where and how to use this configuration. Clear and easy to follow steps are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I have difficulty identifying the added value of this answer compared to the one provided by @muru four years ago. They are essentialyidentical.