# How to make /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/reboot etc. require sudo again in 16.04?

Tags: permissions, sudo, shutdown, root, reboot

For whatever reason, we do no longer need to be root (or using `sudo`) to run `/sbin/shutdown`, `/sbin/reboot` etc.

This seems to be because those executables are now symlinks to `/bin/systemctl` which handles everything as normal user.

However, what if I want `shutdown` and `reboot` to require root authentication again? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd guess polkit rules. Modify http://askubuntu.com/a/570969/158442 as per need (use `pkaction | grep login1` for other rules of interest)

Comment: (an example of rules for requiring admin privileges: http://askubuntu.com/a/744094/158442)

Comment: Isn't this a only if you are the only person logged in. If there is anyone else logged in the system you will be asked to put in the root password.

Comment: That may be not the answer you are expecting, but a similar behaviour can be caused by another admin user having editted your '/etc/sudoers'. If this is what is causing your issue then you can change it back by typing `sudo visudo` and check if there is a line with the path to these executables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Systemd does indeed handle the `shutdown`, `reboot` and other commands, and [the default privileges assigned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209766/70524) are permissive. To change this, you need to create a Polkit rule. Create a `.pkla` file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` (say, `confirm-shutdown.pkla`) containing:

```
[Confirm shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.*
ResultActive=auth_admin_keep
```

The various shutdown, reboot, etc. commands are, in Polkit terms,  actions in `org.freedesktop.login1`, for example, `org.freedesktop.login1.power-off`, `org.freedesktop.login1.reboot`, etc. The specific problem here is the default configuration, which is in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`:

```xml
<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.power-off">
        <description>Power off the system</description>
        ...
        <defaults>
                <allow_any>auth_admin_keep</allow_any>
                <allow_inactive>auth_admin_keep</allow_inactive>
                <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
        </defaults>
```

Note that it allows the active user to power off, reboot, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chmod` command.

- If you want to give access to only root, you can write:

  ```
  chmod 700 directory/to/the/file
  ```
- If you want to give permisson to the root and the sudo group then you can write:

  ```
  chmod 770 directory/to/the/file
  ```
- If you want to change the group of the file from sudo to an another (like a user or admins) you need to type in:

  ```
  chown owner:group directory/to/the/file
  ```
- If you want to revert back, run:

  ```
  chown root:sudo filedirectory
  ```

**Note**: you may have to use `sudo` to these command, or have logged in the root account

Comment: Note that attempting to change the permissions of the link will change the permissions of the target (in this case `/bin/systemctl`) so running chmod /sbin/shutdown will impact all the links pointing to `/bin/systemctl` as the permissions to `bin/systemctl` will be changed as confirmed by the command $ `ll /bin/systemct`l -rwx------ 1 root root 659848 Jan 18 16:04 /bin/systemctl*

Comment: If you need to change it back, the default permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 659848 Jan 18 16:04 /bin/systemctl`

Answer (score 0):

As [changing permissions of a symlink on a Linux system](https://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks) doesn't change the permissions of the link but instead the file it points to (In Ubuntu at least). I would think the safest way to accomplish this would be to remove the link, and recreate it with the required [umask](http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_umask.html) to obtain the result you desire.

Another related post can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score -1):

You can make a script that checks if user is running it with root permissions or not.

Then it will run systemctl command or return error.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Sorry, you are not root."
    exit 1
else
    (systemctl shutdown command)
fi
```

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=479255)

Comment: What's to stop a non-root user from simply bypassing this script?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change its permissions in terminal. You could make it executable only by by a certain group, such as wheel or admin. Sadly (or perhaps fortunately), a file can only have one group ownership so chown simply wouldn't work by itself. Try "sudo chown root:wheel /sbin/shutdown" and then "sudo chmod g+x /sbin/shutdown". This will make the file executable only by root and admins(shudders) and sudoers will be required to enter their passwords.

Comment: The "wheel" group is a thing of Arch Linux and maybe other distributions, but definitely not on Ubuntu btw.

Comment: This is not effective. A user can just download a systemctl binary from somewhere else, and run that instead.

Comment: @Robie, you could do that with any solution. You could hold down the power button. My solution works for what he asks.