# Create an exact root user

Tags: command-line, server, 17.10

Is it possible to create a sudo user who has exact privileges of a root user ?
If so can you guide me through how to create one using cmd.

Ex: I have created a sudo user who can't restart for some reason. He can always do sudo -i and then restart, but is there some other way which makes the user by default have all the permissions.

I know it's vulnerable but since it runs on local network it's fine.

Comment: If you are aware of the vulnerabilities, you can enable root user by setting a password.

Comment: @ravery Since there is a need of multiple users accessing the system concurrently.

Comment: What happens when they try to restart?

Comment: Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.

@muru The above error shows up

Comment: What command did they try? And how?

Comment: Just `reboot` was the command

Comment: As far as I remember, with transition to `systemd` the shutdown and reboot now do not require root privilege , see https://askubuntu.com/q/789058/295286  Try to poke around polkit settings as shown in that post, maybe server settings are different from desktop. But any user that is in sudo group can just do `sudo shutdown -r now`. You can also edit `/etc/sudoers` file to run a command without requiring password, there's questions around on AskUbuntu about that,too.

Comment: Am trying to restart not shutdown

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy that's correct...when zero or one users are logged in. Sudo/Root is still required when more than one user is logged in.

Comment: This seems like a systemd bug, rather than a Sudo/Root issue. Please take a look at the current systemd bugs at launchpad.net, and see if your problem is one of those. If not, please report the new bug. They cannot fix it if they don't know about it.

Comment: @user535733 for me this is true under 16.04, but under 17.10 `reboot` has different behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeOd6.gif

Comment: @pa4080 fascinating (*and an excellent use of screen recording!*) Please file a bug report - the systemd developers did not intend for any single user without admin privs to terminate everybody's sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user, let's call him `myuser`, grant `myuser` the same privileges as `root` and set a password for this account:

```
$ sudo useradd -ou 0 -g 0 myuser
$ sudo passwd myuser
```

If you have already had a user `myuser` and you want to grant him `root` privileges (make him a second root user):

```
$ grep myuser /etc/passwd
myuser:x:1001:1001::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

For this, it is required to edit the file `/etc/passwd` and just change `UID` and `GID` to `0`.

Comment: If I perform restart after creating the user, it asks for root password.

Comment: Have you created a user with password?                                                                        Can you use the string u provided for the below command,                      
$ sudo passwd nullbyte

Comment: Yes I did as specified but still it asks for root password to reboot

Comment: Not sure Mate. Let me try out in some time. Update you the same.

Comment: Bro it works finally

Comment: That's nice. Cool.